# LetsEncrypt ACMEv2 updates with CertifyTheWeb

Tags: ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

I have a number of Windows 2016 servers configured with CertifyTheWeb's LetsEncrypt application. This secures a number of IIS certs.

I've received a notification that the ACMEv1 protocol is due to be deprecated in June 2020 and that I need to switch to the ACMEv2 protocol, this also has a list of servers that have used the v1 Protocol to renew certs in the last 30 days.

I picked a single server, installed the latest version of CertifyTheWeb (presuming that this would default to the newer protocol) waited for the next notification, unfortunately it still showed that it was using the old protocol.

I've had a look around the settings in CertifyTheWeb and did some googling, but didn't see how to change this. I'm sure it's something very simple that I've overlooked (and will feel rightfully silly for when it is pointed out) however I'd like to get the updates completed and rolled out in good order so that the cert renewals don't fail.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was answered by 'webprofusion' on [CertifyTheWeb community](https://community.certifytheweb.com/t/v4-1-6-using-acmev2/734):

> V4.x only uses ACME V2.
>
> You are receiving an email from Let’s Encrypt either because:
>
> - you have an older certificate you have not yet renewed
> - or because they just haven’t realized you’ve upgraded (because the upgrade also recreates your account with them).
>
> If all of your certificates are now being managed by v4 of the app
>   there is nothing more that you need to do.

Comment: Thanks for that - I'll roll out version 4 of the client across all the servers.